# Jeopardy: The answer is: A shape described by a simple algebraic equation. Q: What is a differential equation that yields that shape?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Suppose I have some process that I believe to be the result of a differential equation. It would be reasonable to regard this as the path of a point particle in some notional space. Suppose further that I know the exact shape thaat the path follows, and it is one with a simple description, such as a conic section or a polynomial in two dimensions of low order. Is there a determinate series of steps that will give me a differential equation which has my specified shape as a solution for some initial value, or produce increasingly good approximations of that shape on iteration?

If there is an exact solution tell me how to find it.

If there is a way to find increasingly good approximations to a numerical solution, describe that way.

If the answer or answers to the questions above are reasonably clear and straightforward, but hard to describe compactly, I will accept a citation to a work that contains such answers. However if it is a citation to a book-length work, I want a page range or small number of chapters that contains the answer.

Comment: Jordan and Smith, Nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equations is pretty good. Your project is ambitious. What is your background in mathematics?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking can be done in a trivial way, although the resulting differential may not be very meaningful. For the sake of simplicity, imagine that you have a known function $f(t)$, and you want to find a differential equation that has $f(t)$ as solution.

1. Compute (for instance) $f'(t)+f(t):= w(t)$, which is now a given function.
2. You can trivially see that $f(t)$ is a solution of the differential equation $u'(t) + u(t)= w(t)$

You can make $f(t)$ the solution of any differential equations you want, just by choosing appropriate source terms. This can be easily extended to any dimension.